# Turning iptables off on development server permanently?

Tags: linux, networking, centos, iptables

What would be the downsides of turning off iptables permanently on a development environment? I don't like the fact that every time I restart virtual box I must do:

```
service iptables stop
service iptables save
```

I am sure it might help to leave it on or alter is on production, but does it really matter on development?

Answer (score 0):

disabling iptables service is easy:

```
systemctl disable iptables.service
```

The question is why do you want to disable the firewall. Maybe you just want to open bunch of ports for your application servers and leave the firewall on...

**Update:**
This is basic `/etc/sysconfig/iptables` configuration allowing incoming requests on port 22 (ssh):

```
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
-A INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p icmp -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
-A FORWARD -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
COMMIT
```

Comment: Well, lets say I am accessing my host at ip `192.168.1.1` then how do I open a port explicitly for this host?

Comment: q1: 192.168.1.1 is address of your workstation or address of your server?

q2: which port do you want to open?

Comment: I don't know much about vps, but the ip is my address with which I can see my project on my dev server. Port is 22 according to putty that is